# FInd and Remove one or more (with case insensitive) word from text file with PHP

Tags: php, case-insensitive

need help with code to get result like the subject above,

as far, i have use this code

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("pg1-afcCup.txt");
$data = explode(" ", $data);
$remv = "Hosts";
foreach($data as $val) {
    if($remv != $val) {
        $newdata .= $val . " ";
        // print "$val<br />\n";
        }
    }
$newdata = substr($newdata, 0, -1); // remove trailing ,
print "<br /><br />String: $newdata";
$fp = fopen("pg2-afcCup.txt", "w+");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $newdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Above code will delete case-sensitive "Hosts" word inside pg1-afcCup.txt, and rewrite and save it in pg2-afcCup.txt.

how to make it insensitive, and find more than just one word (fill $remv with more words)?

ps: i have tried preg_replace with no success...

Comment: use an array and use `in_array()` for checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("pg1-afcCup.txt");
$data = explode(" ", $data);
$remv = "hosts";
$newdata = "";
foreach($data as $val) {
if($remv != strtolower($val)) {
$newdata .= $val . " ";
// print "$val<br />\n";
}
}
$newdata = substr($newdata, 0, -1); // remove trailing ,
print "<br /><br />String: $newdata";
$fp = fopen("pg2-afcCup.txt", "w+");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $newdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

It converts the string to lower case and then checks. So, this should work fine.

For multiple filters

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents("pg1-afcCup.txt");
$data = explode(" ", $data);
$remv = array("hosts","other", "somemore");
$newdata="";
foreach($data as $val) {
if (! in_array(strtolower($val),$remv) ) {
$newdata .= $val . " ";
// print "$val<br />\n";
}
}
$newdata = substr($newdata, 0, -1); // remove trailing ,
print "<br /><br />String: $newdata";
$fp = fopen("pg2-afcCup.txt", "w+");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $newdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have try that source, but the output become some strange Chinese letter (潈瑳⁳楫正摥琠敨....)

Comment: Now try this, I have edited the answer. Now it works pretty fine.

Comment: Thanks, thats code just doing fine, :D
now the problem just about adding more than 1 word to filter...

btw, that was fast ^_^

Comment: Well, look at the solution now.

Comment: try make $remv as an array to make it contains multiple words?

Comment: Look at the edited solution for multiple filters. Refresh the page and check my answer.

Comment: yes, i have tried to add an array, an works like charm, 
thanks for your assistance, sailesh ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one with preg_replace

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("pg.txt");
$data = explode(" ", $data);
$remv = "Hosts";
$pattern = '/^hosts$/i'; # if you need to erase the exact word
#$pattern = '/hosts/i'; # erasing a substring
foreach($data as $val) {
    $newdata .= preg_replace($pattern, "", $val) . " ";
}
$newdata = substr($newdata, 0, -1); // remove trailing ,
print "<br /><br />String: $newdata";
$fp = fopen("pg2-afcCup.txt", "w+");
$fw = fwrite($fp, $newdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this one too with no success, the output become empty,
wonder what have been wrong here...

Comment: Could you paste the testing data?